# Get top-level namespace in Ruby

Tags: ruby, namespaces, diagnostics

How can I do this in Ruby?:

Sometimes for diagnostics in interpreted language, it's faster for me to make a quick alteration to my code, tossing an object into the top-level namespace, then mess with it there in an interactive environment.

In Python, I add this to my code:

```
import __main__
__main__.[field] = [my problematic object]
```

...then run the file with a command `python -i [myfilename]`.  Any idea how I can get access to the top-level namespace in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) for this.

Run `gem install pry` to install pry. Then add the following code where you want to start an interactive session.

```
require 'pry'
binding.pry
```

An example of an interactive session.

```
$ cat debug.rb
a = 7
b = 6
product = a * b
require 'pry'
binding.pry
puts "The answer is: #{product}"

$ ruby debug.rb

From: debug.rb @ line 5 in Object#N/A:

     1: a = 7
     2: b = 6
     3: product = a * b
     4: require 'pry'
 =>  5: binding.pry
     6: puts "The answer is: #{product}"
pry(main)> product
=> 42
pry(main)> product = -1 * a * b
=> -42
pry(main)> exit
The answer is: -42
```

Comment: So is pry a debugging gem?  (Don't have time to try it out at the moment.)  I'm sorry to be so uninformed, but I'm not familiar with the `$` notation in Ruby.  Is that something you can explain breifly?

Comment: Pry is just an alternative to IRB, with many more features. Which `$` are you talking about? `$ cat debug.rb`? That's the shell.